# Cannot convert from IEnumerable<List> to List

Tags: linq, collections

I am working on these lists to get an item that matches the selected item from the combobox.

```
private void InitializaMessageElement()
{
    if (_selectedTransactionWsName != null)
    {
```

1. get a transaction webservice name matching the selected item from the drop down here the output=TestWS  which is correct

   ```
   var getTranTypeWsName = TransactionTypeVModel
        .GetAllTransactionTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(transTypes => 
                transTypes.WsMethodName == _selectedTransactionWsName);
   ```
2. Loop the list of wsnames from the treenode list. Here it gives me all the node I have which is correct.

   ```
   var wsNameList = MessageElementVModel
        .GetAllTreeNodes().Select(ame => 
                ame.Children).ToList();//. == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName);
   ```
3. find the getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName in the  wsNameList. Here is where I have the problem:

   ```
      var msgElementList = MessageElementVModel.GetAllTreeNodes()
                                                    .Select(ame =>   ame.Children).Where(c =>
                                                        {
                                                            c.Where(d =>     getTranTypeWsName != null && d.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName);
                                                            return false;
                                                        });
   ```

my MsgElement list:

```
    var _msgElementList = new ObservableCollection<MessageElementViewModel>(msgElementList);
    this.messageElements = _msgElementList;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageElements");
}
```

Here it is returning wrong data. It returns all the list I have a non filtered one.
Why is my out put inconsistent? I am new to LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code seems problematic:

```
   var msgElementList = wsNameList.SingleOrDefault(x =>
            {
                x.Where(ame => ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName);
            return true;

            });
```

You were expecting a list but you used the SingleOrDefault(), which is meant to be used in retrieving a single record.

Try this, which will retrieve msgElementList. No need to get all tree nodes first and store it in wsNameList:

```
// Assumed that Name is a property of Children
    var msgElementList = MessageElementVModel.GetAllTreeNodes()
        .Select(ame => ame.Children).Where(c => c.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName).ToList();
```

Comment: I have to go one more level deep to get that property Name. Something like.                                                                           var msgElementList = MessageElementVModel.GetAllTreeNodes()
        .Select(ame => ame.Children).Where(c =>
            {
                c.Select(d => d.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName);
                return true;
            }
                    ).ToList();      but this gives me error.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me which property of Children can we get the Name? So I can adjust the linq query. Thanks

Comment: The name is the property of the child name.

Comment: Have you tried my code without editing it? Because AFAIC, that's legit.

Comment: Hi Ben this fixed it.  var msgElementList = wsNameList.SelectMany(x => x.Where(ame => getTranTypeWsName != null && ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName)).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

var msgElementList = wsNameList.SelectMany(x => x.Where(ame => getTranTypeWsName != null && ame.Name == getTranTypeWsName.WsMethodName)).ToList();